# MongoDB: behavior of $not and indexing

Tags: mongodb, operators, indexing

I thought in MongoDB addition of indexes does not affect the result of queries. However I have encountered one such case where that happens.

There is a collection named `scores`. In absence of indexes, the following query:

```
db.scores.find({score: {$not: {$gt: 100}}})
```

returns records for which the value of `score` is not greater than 100 and records for which the key `score` is missing.

Adding the index on `score` field however causes MongoDB to exclude the records for which the key `score` is missing. Is there a way to prevent this? Please note that the indexes are essential in our case.

Comment: What options are you passing to `ensureIndex`?

Comment: I am doing: `db.scores.ensureIndex( { score: 1 })`

Answer (score 0):

When MongoDB uses the index, it's only finding results in the index. It is unfortunate that it behaves differently depending on whether it's done a complete table scan or just the index.

While there are several ways of handling this, you could do something like this:

```
db.scores.find({ $or : [ 
                    {score: { $exists: false  }}, 
                    {score: {$not: {$gt: 100}}}]})
```

That would just check for either condition to be `true`. If you check the results of `explain`, you'll see that it uses the index for both conditions.

Although, if you could just add the `score` to all documents, it may perform better as the index usage will be more efficient.

Comment: This is giving perfect result.
However running `explain` on the query, it shows that is scanning all documents except one without score. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: It is using the index, but `$exists:false` will need to do a lot of scanning. I'd suggest adding a `score: 0` to all documents would be a lot more efficient for the type of query that you're interested in.